# Netbeans Test Results first functional test skipped

Tags: php, netbeans, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

The issue is, when I run my functional tests from within Netbeans, I get '2 tests passed, 1 test skipped' for each functional test class that I write (utilizing Internet Explorer and Firefox on my work machine to test).

Example output in Netbeans "Test Results" window:

```
ApplicationTest Skipped
ApplicationTest: Internet Explorer passed
ApplicationTest: Firefox passed
```

From the command line, it just works:

```
Time: 11 seconds, Memory: 7.50Mb

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

Is there any way I can stop this non-existent first test from showing up in the Test Results window?
This isn't really an issue, I'd just like an accurate percentage of functional tests that pass without having to verify that they all passed - scrolling through the long list of results.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I'd like to make note that this only happens with functional tests utilizing Selenium within Netbeans. Unit tests work fine and do not report any additional skipped tests.

Comment: Not sure the issue, but it might appear that it is an additional test pass just in Netbeans that is getting skipped, since the actual tests for both browsers seem to be passing in full.

Comment: Yeah, I saw some other people mentioning they had this problem on another forum and mentioned upgrading selenium. I have a relatively new version of selenium though, but I may try upgrading anyhow.